# Error #1009 utilizing event listener in external class file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

(New to AS3/Flash so go easy on me if I'm oblivious to something...)

Trying to utilize external class files to create a continuous scrolling background image. I got it to work by putting it in the document class file, but trying to put it in its own external class file and calling it from the document class file brings up the error in my title.

Document Class File:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    import org.masteringmoneybasics.piggy._class_BG



    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public function Main() {
            //Create instance of background class
            new _class_BG();
            } 

    }
}
```

External Class File:

```
package org.masteringmoneybasics.piggy {

    import flash.display.*
    import flash.events.Event
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;

    public class _class_BG{
        //BG Variables
        var scrollSpeed:uint = 6;
        var bgLeft:Bitmap
        var bgRight:Bitmap

        [Embed(source="../../../assets/side_of_mountain.png")]
            private var bgImage:Class;

        public function _class_BG() {
                    //This adds two instances of the background to the stage
            bgLeft = new bgImage();
            bgRight = new bgImage();
            bgLeft.height = 500;
            bgRight.height = bgLeft.height;
            bgLeft.width = 1300;
            bgRight.width = bgLeft.width;
            bgLeft.x = 0;
            bgRight.x = bgLeft.width;
            addChild(bgLeft);
            addChild(bgRight);

            //Adds an event lsitener to the stage
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveScroll); //<<<<<< ERROR HERE
        }

        public function moveScroll(e:Event):void{
            bgLeft.x -= scrollSpeed;
            bgRight.x -= scrollSpeed;

            if(bgLeft.x < -bgLeft.width){
                bgLeft.x = bgRight.x + bgRight.width;
            }else if(bgRight.x < -bgRight.width){
                bgRight.x = bgLeft.x + bgLeft.width;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

If I remove the stage. reference in the event listener, it runs without errors but the images don't appear on the stage like they are supposed to.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Only the top level Displayable has access to scene. What's more, it is read-only, which means that you cannot pass it through the original stage attribute.

The simplest way to go would be... I don't know, perhaps passing the stage to your constructor? The relavant parts of the constructor would be:

```
    public function _class_BG(myStage : Stage) {

        // SNIP

        //Adds an event lsitener to the stage
        myStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveScroll);
    }
```

And in Main (in which you do have acces to the stage):

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    public function Main() {
        //Create instance of background class
        addChild(new _class_BG(stage));
    } 
}
```

You should think about some other means of building your logic, passing stage around will get hairy quickly. But it should work.

**EDIT:**

stage -> myStage; also, addChild in Main().

Comment: So would you say I'm utilizing the external class file in an incorrect way? I'm used to top-down and function/call based programming and OOP is a new concept to me.

Comment: Either case, I think you meant myStage.addEventListener? I tried both ways. stage. returns the same error. myStage. runs without error but no images again.

Comment: I saw somewhere that you can't extend the class to a display object (MovieClip/Sprite) or else the class creates its own stage... so I removed that and it returns an error with addChild() not being a recognized method (cause I believe it needs MovieClip to be extended into the class to utilize it)

Comment: I'm thinking... maybe I need to pass bgLeft/bgRight into the function... have it build the properties and return... then from Main, throw in the event listener calling the moveScroll function from the external class instead?

Comment: @Mechaflash: you are thinking too much into it. Really - you just need to pass the stage. a, well, I lied, You also need to display your sprite. Let me edit the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You tried to In Main class external class initialized in stage. In fact, stage not arrived. see a your _class_BG, addChild() is a little wrong. because you not check Main class, perfectly added stage.

FlashBuilder this problem must be careful. first added to stage on Main class after  external class(related DisplayObject) fully loaded or initialized.

refer a following code.

In _class_BG Class Carefully `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);`

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip; 

        public class Main extends MovieClip {
            public function Main() {
                var sp:_class_BG = new _class_BG();
                addChild(sp);
            }   
        }
}
```

---

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class _class_BG extends Sprite {
        //BG Variables
        private var scrollSpeed:uint = 6;
        private var bgLeft:Bitmap
        private var bgRight:Bitmap

        [Embed(source="../asset/myTestImage.png")]
        private var bgImage:Class;

        public function _class_BG() 
        {
            if(!stage)
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            else
                init();
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
             removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            //This adds two instances of the background to the stage
            bgLeft = new bgImage();
            bgRight = new bgImage();
            bgLeft.height = 500;
            bgRight.height = bgLeft.height;
            bgLeft.width = 1300;
            bgRight.width = bgLeft.width;
            bgLeft.x = 0;
            bgRight.x = bgLeft.width;
            addChild(bgLeft);
            addChild(bgRight);

            //Adds an event lsitener to the stage
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveScroll);
        }

        public function moveScroll(e:Event):void{
            bgLeft.x -= scrollSpeed;
            bgRight.x -= scrollSpeed;

            if(bgLeft.x < -bgLeft.width){
                bgLeft.x = bgRight.x + bgRight.width;
            }else if(bgRight.x < -bgRight.width){
                bgRight.x = bgLeft.x + bgLeft.width;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: making the changes to my code, I now receive errors "Call to a possibly undefined method addChild" in my Main class, and "Access of undefined property sp" in the addChild() in my Main class as well.

Comment: Did you write something like the code above? Can you give me a link to your source. Reviewing'll